# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound index.html

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to learn flask by creating a simple blog web site. My file structure for my project looks like this:

- flaskBlog

  - setup.py
  - flaskBlog

    - __init__.py
    - views.py
    - templates

      - index.html

So I've got my templates directory at the same level as my __init__.py and views.py which looks like this:

```
# __init__.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('__name__')
import flaskBlog.views
```

```
# views.py
from flaskBlog import app
from flask import render_template
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

When I use `flask run` it starts like normal and tells me its running on localhost:5000, but when I try to navigate to it I get a jinja error saying `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound index.html`.   Every similar question I've seen on here is answered by saying to ensure that my app and my templates folder are on the same level but I'm still getting this error. Why can't the index template be found?

Answer (score 1):

You can either put the templates dir a level up (next to your blog app) or you can define the path you want to load the templates from like so:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#application-object (check the template_folder arg)

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that the __init__.py was my flask app because that's where I was creating it. After moving the templates directory up to the same level as the inner flaskBlog directory it is now working.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your folder structure like this:

```
flaskBlog
 templates
   index.py
 setup.py
 flaskBlog
  __init__.py
  views.py
```

The templates folder should be in the same directory as your setup.py